# jqGrid - Is it possible to get object properties ondblClickRow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, jqgrid, ondblclick

I have the following jqGrid:

[image]

I make an AJAX call to display elements on that grid. I wanted to show more items on the grid (same tab) and made another AJAX call.

So, I created 2 arrays. The first array stores the result of Ajax Call 1, the second array stores the result of Ajax Call 2.

I concatenated these arrays and displayed them on the grid:

```
var test3 = test1.concat(test2);
thegrid.addJSONData(test3);
```

So far so good, the only problem is, that when I want double click the item on the grid, it can only use the same path for every item, meaning that it can open only 1 form and not different ones.

That's because when clicking the grid, it calls this function:

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
    onDoubleClickGrid(rowid, iRow, iCol, e, divname, listname);
}
```

Here's the entire function:

```
function onDoubleClickGrid(rowid, iRow, iCol, e, divname, listname, useFormToOpen) {

    var rowData = $("#" + divname).getRowData(rowid);
    var curID = rowData.Id;
    var useForm = "EditForm.aspx";

    if (checkNull(useFormToOpen)!="") {
        useForm = useFormToOpen;
    }

    var curPath = "/MM/Lists/" + listname;
    // var curPath = "/nderungsantrag/Lists/" + listname;
    var url = curPath + "/" + useForm + "?ID=" + curID;
    openInDialog(dlgWidth, dlgHeight, true, true, true, url);
}
```

I tried working with flags, but these won't work here because the objects are all in the merged array, and it can't differentiate them.

**Is it possible to get the object values of the element that was clicked ondblClickRow?**
Because then I could use a for loop and check for the properties of the object. Depending on what property it has, I could change the path. Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi, can you some how make this runnable  with dummy data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ondblClickRow has a parameter event (the 4 one). Here you can get the element like this (if I understand correct the requierment):

```
ondblClickRow : function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement; // this is what you need
    ....
}
```

Your  curPath is a combination of one constant value and one variable

```
var curPath = "/MM/Lists/" + listname
```

If *listname* variable does not change during double click the row you always will have the same curPath. I do not see if you change it when the row is double clicked.